# Can't open up the virt-manager from Mac

Tags: windows, macos, qemu, kvm

I am following the following tutorial to setup the virt-manager and Windows

https://getlabsdone.com/12-easy-steps-to-install-windows-10-on-linux-kvm/

However, I can't call the virt-manager from my SSH terminal. It is giving me the following error and warning:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused 
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused 
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused 
(virt-manager:4755): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:47:24.124: cannot open display:
```

I have installed the X11-XQuartz in my Mac, and tried SSH -X user@ip. However, the error and warning are still alive! Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: I installed a virt-manager in my Mac. However, it is not able to connect the server! But my libvirtb is running on my server. https://prnt.sc/qe841g

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_host_configuration_and_guest_installation_guide/app_tcp_ports find the possible reason, but I can't find the /etc/sysconfig/libvirtd in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Can you open any graphical application? That error is not virt-manager specific. There's probably something wrong with your X11 install or setup

Comment: Yes, the server is missing the X11 server! Now it is fixed